# Are classes that are not directly used in views still models (MVVM)?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have the following question to MVVM:

Is a class that will never be directly used in a view (just as part of a model) a model too?
And do I have to structure it that way?

For example:

I have a user model which has an address property.

```
class UserModel
{
    private Address _address;
    public Address Address
    {
        get => return _address;
        set => _address = value;
    }
}
```

Do I have to create an AddressModel and AddressViewModel or can I just use a single Address class with data und logic?

An explanation would be very helpful cause I want to create a class diagram. :)

Comment: "Do I have to" - You dont *have* to do anything. It is up to you for the design. ViewModels help you model things that aren't really part of your model, but are useful to the view (i.e. colour or visibility of an element, or a readable version of some attribute). In this narrow example, it doesn't seem having a viewmodel would be much use - however if the app will grow its probably best to include one now, so that later on when it is required you already have it in place and don't need to change other code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best answer to this is why do you care? If a class is used from a view, then this poses some structure requirements to it like implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. If you are not using this class from a view, you don't have these requirements. You can still implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in case you eventually use the class in a view, but you don't have to, particularly if it is clear that the functionality provided by the class will never be exposed to the view, like you must not show the address of a user due to legal issues or similar.

However, that sounds unrealistic to me. Most likely, you will want to at least display the users address and that makes `Address` a view model.